# Form Controls difference in using .shapes and using .buttons in code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have put several buttons in this macro and everything works great and looks great but I had a question about the code. As you can see down below, in this snippet of code, while using `With Activesheet`, the code then uses `.Shapes` AND `.BUTTONS`. It looks like `.Shapes` has more to do with sizing the button after it has been placed? and `.BUTTONS` has more to do with what it looks like and what it does?

I am just wondering what the difference in these are because at one point I use `.BUTTONS` to add the buttons, and then I use `.shapes` to change the size of the buttons. But then I use `.Shapes` to tell it what to do `OnAction` when clicked instead of `.BUTTONS`. What exactly is the difference in these properties? (or whatever it is called I am not sure) It just seems like they kind of intertwine and I am not too sure which to use and when.

```
With Activesheet
    .BUTTONS.Add(53.25, 36.75, 190.5, 41.25).Select
    .Shapes("Button 6").IncrementLeft 222.75
    .Shapes("Button 6").IncrementTop 147
    .BUTTONS("Button 6").Text = "Mexmo MFG"

    .BUTTONS("Button 10").Text = "10"
    .BUTTONS("Button 10").name = "Button 10"
    .BUTTONS("Button 11").Text = "11"
    .BUTTONS("Button 11").name = "Button 11"
    .BUTTONS("Button 12").Text = "12"
    .BUTTONS("Button 12").name = "Button 12"

    .Shapes("Atlanta MFG").OnAction = "Atlanta"
    .Shapes("Denver MFG").OnAction = "Denver"
    .Shapes("Jackson MFG").OnAction = "Jackson"
    .Shapes("Louisville MFG").OnAction = "Louisville"
End With
```

Comment: Shapes is just a collection of all the Shape objects on the specified sheet. So it contains as a subset all your buttons and anything else in your WB that is a shape (charts, Texboxes, etc.)  The .buttons() seems to be a collection of all buttons in your workbook.  They may do the same thing, but I would stay with the .buttons() .  The Buttons mouseclick event could be used to trigger your macros to run.

Comment: Sooooo basically all buttons are shapes but not all shapes are buttons? maybe perhaps? haha thank you for your answer. It helps make a bit more sense actually put together with that other answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

Some properties are only available and could be tweaked using `Shape` object only. That is why your code has `Buttons` and `Shapes` collections.

Most of the objects that inherit from `Shapes` usually exposes `ShapeRange` property that returns the Shape object. You can simply use that and access all the related properties.

---

Example:

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
    .Buttons.Add(53.25, 36.75, 190.5, 41.25).Select
    .Shapes("Button 6").IncrementLeft 222.75

    '/ This works same as Shapes("Button 6")
    .Buttons("Button 6").ShapeRange.IncrementTop 147

    .Shapes("Button 6").IncrementTop 147
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah very nice! Thank you. I was thinking some of the actions I was doing such as `Shapes.OnAction` should be `BUTTONS.OnAction` because I was clicking on the button you know? But like you said it kind of is if I just do it another way. It makes a bit more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @cyoashu's answer, it's worth noting that the `.Buttons.Add()` method *returns the added button*, so you can use that directly in your `With` block:

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(53.25, 36.75, 190.5, 41.25)
        .Name = "Blah"
        .Text = "Blah"
        .OnAction = "DoSomething"
        With .ShapeRange
            .IncrementLeft 222.75
            .IncrementTop 147
            .IncrementTop 147
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

... which spares you from having to know anything about the name of the just-added button.